# Android: ArrayList Move Item to Position 0

Tags: android, collections, arraylist, swap

I have an **ArrayList** and I need to make sure a specific item is at the 0 position and if it is not, I need to move it there. The item has an `isStartItem` boolean on it, so I can easily find the specific item I need to be in position 0 but then how do I go about moving it to the right position?

I am assuming I need to use something like this:

```
for(int i=0; i<myArray.size(); i++){    
    if(myArray.get(i).isStartItem()){
        Collection.swap(myArray, i, 0);
    }
}
```

But this does not seem to work...

Comment: What do you mean by "this does not seem to work". Does it generate an error, or, does it throw exception, or, simply the swap doesn't happen ?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need to use `Collections` class's `swap` method. `Collections`, with an `s` at the end.

Change -

```
Collection.swap(myArray, i, 0);
```

to this -

```
Collections.swap(myArray, i, 0);
```

Take a look at [this](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Collections-Data-Structure/SwapelementsofJavaArrayList.htm) example.

[Collection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) and [Collections](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html) are two different things in Java. The first one is an interface, the second one is a class. The later one has a static swap method, but the former one doesn't.

Comment: Oops...I just forgot the s when I was typing out the question.

Comment: @ryandlf: Oh.....then could you tell me what do you mean by "doesn't seem to work" ?

Comment: does this actually move the element that is at 0 to i when it moves the element at i to 0? if so then i don't think it is what OP is looking for. I usually just simply create a new object to save what's at i, then call .remove(index) to to pull it out, then call .add(index, object) with index being 0. yada yada

Comment: Really happy to got this answer, I am trying to from one hour but it wasnt work for me , Using this working fine for me

Answer (score 6):

I don't know what `Collection.swap` is, but this code should work:

```
for(int i=0; i<myArray.size(); i++){    
    if(myArray.get(i).isStartItem()){
        Collections.swap(myArray, i, 0);
        break;
    }
}
```

Or you can do it long-hand:

```
for(int i=0; i<myArray.size(); i++){    
    if(myArray.get(i).isStartItem()){
        Object thing = myArray.remove(i); // or whatever type is appropriate
        myArray.add(0, thing);
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There are 2 ways of moving an item to the desired position in the ArrayList.

**1. Swap the items**

> Collections.swap(myArray, i, 0);

--> Here position "i" will be moved to 0th position and all the other items in between this range will remain as it is.

**2. Shift the items**

> myArray.add(0,myArray.remove(i))

--> Here item at position "i" will be removed and added to the 0th position. Here all the other items position will be shifted as you're adding a new item at 0.

Hope this will helps you to understand the difference between swap and shift the position. Use the solution according to your requirement.

Answer (score -3):

You can use the set function of Arraylist.

```
set(position,object)
```

Comment: That will just replace whatever was in the arraylist at 0 with `object`. I don't think OP wants to lose any elements, just reorder them.

Comment: I did try and this method and it did exactly as Ted described.