# RefreshListView returning item at bottom not top?

Tags: android, listadapter

I have used RefreshableListView in my app to refresh the listview it is working fine but the problem is it return the new item at the end of the list but i want to return at top please help?

```
 list.setOnRefreshListener(new OnRefreshListener() {
               @Override
               public void onRefresh() {

               }

            @Override
            public void onRefresh(RefreshableListView listView) {

                   new NewDataTask().execute();// TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
           });


private class NewDataTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> {

                @Override
                protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(Void... params) {

                    new_request_feeds("my url");  //method which return json from the url

                    return fetch;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> fetch) {

                    // This should be called after refreshing finished       
                    if(fetch.size()!=0)
                       {
                        adapter=new CustomListAdapter(getActivity(), R.id.list_ongoing, fetch);                                
                          list.setAdapter(adapter);                        

                       }
                       else
                       {   

                           System.out.println("no feeds");
                           Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "no feeds", 3000).show();
                       }// Here if you wish to do future process for ex. move to another activity do here

                    list.completeRefreshing();
                    super.onPostExecute(result);
                }
            }
```

Comment: where are u adding new values ??

Comment: doinbackgroung will return an arraylist called fetch and i am passing this fetch to onpostexecute inside customlist adapter to set the list again with new data that reside in fetch

Comment: try to add your data at initial index in arraylist .. that should work

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you, you can put the item in the top like this:
when you add the item to the ArrayList, add it like this:

```
myArrayList.add(0,item);// 0 is the item position
```

hope it's helpful
**Regards**

Comment: doInbackground is returning an arraylist of hashmap not an single item.

Comment: @ShashankAgarwal You can change the items positions with Collections class, swap function. see example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7035507/android-arraylist-move-item-to-position-0  hope this works