# Hide TabLayout.Tab which integrated with ViewPager

Tags: android, android-tablayout

How to hide a tab in TabLayout?

My TabLayout integrated with ViewPager so I cannot use TabItem for each Tab.

I was init my TabLayout and ViewPager like this. Thanks

```
    tabTitles = new ArrayList<>();
    tabTitles.add("Tab   1");
    tabTitles.add("Tab   2"); // I want to hide this tab and set visible later.
    tabTitles.add("Tab      3");
    tabTitles.add("Tab   4");
    tabTitles.add("Tab  5");

    adapter = new ProfileBirefAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), this, tabTitles);

    vpgMain.setAdapter(adapter);

    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(vpgMain);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can "hide" a tab, but you can remove & add it back again, as it will look like you've hidden it.

---

**Step 1 - "Hide"**

Remove your desired tab from the ArrayList:

```
tabTitles.remove(2);
```

Notify your ViewPager's Adapter so the update will take place

```
vpgMain.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
```

---

**Step 2 - "Show"**

Add your tab back again
(**Note**: to put it back in the same position, use [this guy's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7035534/6184356/) answer to manipulate your ArrayList)

```
tabTitles.add("Tab   2");
```

And notify your adapter again:

```
vpgMain.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged();
```

---

Good luck!

Comment: It will work some cases. But my case is hiding, meaning data inside fragment still not loss. I'll vote up but still want to find other way to solve my problem.

Comment: For that, what I would do is change my ArrayList to store fragments instead of simple Strings, and store the Fragment I want to hide prior to its deletion (something like Fragment frag = tabTitles.get(2)). Later, i'd add the same fragment to the ArrayList. Another solution could be storing your data with SharedPreferences.